# How to allow a particular user to access the FTP?

Tags: ftp

Anonymous / FTP users are allowed to access the FTP. Suppose if there is a user named as JOE then how can I allow him to access the FTP?

Comment: Could you please tell us what FTP server you are using?

Comment: I made my own with VSFTPD package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you chose vsftpd, as the documentation is notoriously lacking/distributed.  However, to answer your question - the simplest method of allowing registered user access is through enabling local users:

```
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
```

There are other options, dependent on your needs, such as storing users in a database engine like MySQL.  For more pertinent information, please check the following pages:

- [vsftpd configuration](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html) - online man page
- [viki (vsftpd community wiki)](http://viki.brainsware.org/?en/Local_Users) - local user configuration
- [viki (vsftpd community wiki)](http://viki.brainsware.org/?en/Virtual_Users) - virtual user configuration (db)

Assuming you meant you compiled vsftpd when you said "I made my own", then this information should apply.  Let us know if this is an incorrect assumption or if the info provided doesn't assist.